# To Find all sum of 2 Power value combination values of a given column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input Data frame :

| Item | Combinedvalue |
| --- | --- |
| A | 50 |
| B | 20 |
| C | 0 |

Expected Output Data frame :
code_2^31 to code_2^1 columns should create and wherever my possiblecodes are there then the same corresponding code_column should display 1 else 0.
if we have combinedvalue is '0' then all code_columns should fill with '0'

| Item | Combinedcode | possiblecodes | code_2147483648 | code_1073741824 | .till. | code_4 | code_2 | code_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 50 | 2, 16, 32 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 20 | 4, 26 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

One of the stock overflow mate provided the below code but am getting error.

Can someone help me with this requirement. Thanks in Advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def to_codes(x):
    n = np.floor(np.log2(x))
    pow_ = np.flip(np.arange(n + 1))
    # 'y' is the matrix of codes
    y = np.transpose(np.array([np.floor(x / 2**pow_) % 2 for x in x]))
    i_cols = np.apply_along_axis(lambda y: np.any(y != 0), 0, y)
    colnames = ["code_" + str(int(2**pow)) for pow in pow_]
    #
    possiblecodes = np.apply_along_axis(lambda p: ",".join([str(int(codes)) for codes in
    np.flip(pow_[np.where(p > 0)])]), 1, y)
    return pd.DataFrame({"combinedvalue": x, "possiblecodes": possiblecodes, **{colnames[i]: y[:, i] for i                  in np.where(i_cols)}})
```

Comment: What error?  Which line?

Comment: Error is : only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scaler index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very bizarre and complicated way to solve that problem.  There's a large amount of floating point manipulation for what is nothing more than the separation of a value into its bits.

```
import pandas as pd

pow_ = [2**n for n in range(31,-1,-1)]

def to_codes(x):
    # Convert to a binary string.
    xb = [bin(k)[2:].rjust(32,'0') for k in x]
    # Convert to a list of powers of 2.
    xc = [list(int(k) for k in row) for row in xb]

    possibles = []
    for row in xc:
        poss = [str(p) for p,n in zip(pow_,row) if n]
        possibles.append( ','.join(p for p in poss) )

    rows = [[a,b]+c for a,b,c in zip(x, possibles, xc)]
    columns = ['combinedvalue', 'possiblecodes'] + [f'code_{p}' for p in pow_]
    return pd.DataFrame( rows, columns=columns )

print(to_codes([27,39,63]))
```

Output:

```
   combinedvalue  possiblecodes  code_2147483648  ...  code_4  code_2  code_1
0             27       16,8,2,1                0  ...       0       1       1
1             39       32,4,2,1                0  ...       1       1       1
2             63  32,16,8,4,2,1                0  ...       1       1       1

[3 rows x 34 columns]
```